# Logic Apps SharePoint Connector - When a file is created or modified in a folder

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an integration scenario where I need to pull documents from SharePoint Online and submit the content (PDF) to a downstream API. I'm using the When a file is created or modified in a folder trigger to pull documents from a SharePoint library. My question is whether there is a way to set a filter on the trigger so that only PDF documents are retrieved i.e. (*.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can click "Settings" of your trigger.

[image]

And then add the expression `@contains(triggerBody()?['{FilenameWithExtension}'], '.pdf')` to "Trigger Conditions".

[image]

After that, the logic app can just be triggered with file name which contains `.pdf`.

=================================**Upate**==============================

You can change the expression to:

```
@contains(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], '.pdf')
```

Comment: I'm using the "When a file is created or modified in a folder" and not "When a file created or modified (properties only)". @contains(triggerBody()?['{FilenameWithExtension}'], '.pdf') does not seem to work with the trigger I'm using. I'm getting the following error: InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for trigger 'When_a_file_is_created_or_modified_in_a_folder' at line '1' and column '2851': 'The template language function 'contains' expects its first argument 'collection' to be a dictionary (object), an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'.'.

Comment: @ErshadNozari Sorry, I will do some more research and check if there is a solution for your trigger.

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen, that works great thanks a lot! Modified slightly to @endsWith(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], '.pdf')