# Error in Trigger with Filter of a Sharepoint Connector in a Logic App

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am using a filter that checks for excel files in a logic app's sharepoint connector (that monitors new or updated files in a folder) according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911399/logic-apps-sharepoint-connector-when-a-file-is-created-or-modified-in-a-folder): `@endsWith(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], '.xlsx')`

However, the logic app fails with an error: "[...] 'endsWith' expects a parameter of type string as first parameter. The provided value is of type Null."

The file name that the trigger reads seems to be correct.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end, this works fine using the same filter as mentioned.

```
@endsWith(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], '.xlsx')
```

whereas looking at the filter you mentioned it misses the right parenthesis. However, we received the same error when we tried to just run the workflow without creating any file in Sharepoint.

[image]

To make the trigger work you need to upload or modify the .xlsx containing file into your SharePoint folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out that even when the trigger fails due to the null error mentioned in the question, the LA's execution is not triggered. I was expecting the trigger to not have the status 'failed', but 'skipped', as it does when having no trigger condition. So the Trigger throwing an error and failing instead of having the status 'skipped' on null values is the expected behavior?

Comment: Checking for null first using `@and(not(equals(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], null)), endsWith(trigger().outputs?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name'], '.xlsx'))` works. Now the trigger status when the trigger does not fire is 'skipped' instead of "failed".